# How to call add_action after another add_action perform

Tags: ajax, wordpress, hook

I need to run hooks one after another  I had tried the code where first hook working but another hook never called . I am making ajax request ajax request success but section action function (test) not calling.

```
PHP / Wordpress

   <?php
    add_action( 'wp_ajax_my_action', 'my_action' );
    add_action('wp_ajax_my_action' , 'test');
    //add_action('my_action' , 'test');
    function my_action() {
    //global $wpdb; // this is how you get access to the database

    $one = $_POST['valone'];
    $two = $_POST['valtwo'];

    echo $sum = $one+$two;

    //test();

    wp_die(); // this is required to terminate immediately and return a proper response
    }
    function test(){
    echo "Hello World";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are terminating all code when you use `wp_die` in the first hook. This will terminate PHP execution and stop any future code from running. Essentially, it will stop what it was trying to do and return what it has to the AJAX call.

Comment: Thanks for rply but when I transfer test() function top of die() same issue again,

Comment: Are you getting any response at all from the AJAX?

Have you tried changing the priorities? e.g. `add_action( 'wp_ajax_my_action', 'my_action', 10 );` and `add_action('wp_ajax_my_action' , 'test', 20);`

Comment: Yes I am getting response of my_action function but test function not working even I given priority.

Comment: <?php
add_action( 'wp_ajax_my_action', 'my_action' ,  10  );
add_action('wp_ajax_my_action' , 'test' , 20);
function test(){
echo "Hello World";
}
function my_action() {
$one = $_POST['valone'];
$two = $_POST['valtwo'];

echo $sum = $one+$two;
wp_die(); 
}

Comment: Have you tried the same when adding the same actions with no privileges? The actions you have added will only run when the user is logged in.

Comment: ```add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_my_action', 'my_action', 10 );```

Comment: Yes I without priority and with priority same happens and with login or without login same. I can;t call another hook.

Answer (score 0):

You can try calling the same action from your first action like below,

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_my_action', 'my_action' );

function my_action() {//global $wpdb; // this is how you get access to the database
$one = $_POST['valone'];
$two = $_POST['valtwo'];
echo $sum = $one+$two;
//test();
add_action('wp_ajax_my_action' , 'test');
wp_die(); // this is required to terminate immediately and return a proper response
}
function test(){
echo "Hello World";
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: No that is not working. It is because you are adding test function after wp_die.

Comment: You can use exit; instead of wp_die();